# Random "/usr/bin/env: 'python3.6': No such file or directory" when working with dask-yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, dask, skein

I am using `dask-yarn` in local mode in a mapr-cluster. I have unpacked the virtual environment in a shared folder between the nodes.
Some times the workers ( containers ) start properly in the cluster, but sometimes the containers have the next error message in yarn.

`/usr/bin/env: 'python3.6': No such file or directory`

In the meantime, I see a lot of containers with status FAILED ( > 1000 ). My initial provision is around 5 workers however I have to wait around 10 minutes or more until I get the initial provision.

The next is my `/etc/dask/yarn.yaml` configuration

```
yarn:
  specification: null        
  name: dask                 
  queue: default             
  deploy-mode: local        
  environment: "venv://<shared_location>"
  tags: []                  
  user: ''                  
  host: "host_name"             
  port: 8788                    
  dashboard-address: ":17439"   

  scheduler:                 
    vcores: 1
    memory: 2GiB

  worker:                   
    vcores: 1
    memory: 2GiB
    restarts: -1            
    env: {'SOME_VAR':'some_value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the problem: Some of the nodes didnt have the same python version and in the same location. Since I am using a virtual environment. The virtual environment expected to have python in the same location in all Nodes